# Implementing Kleene star operator * (sort of) in C program

Tags: c, kleene-star

For any user input string A ,with at least one instance of the star operator `*`,verify that input string B can be produced by A. For example: go`*`s can produce the strings goes,goners,goals etc.
I can't figure out a way to implement this. I thought i could compile some specific regex for each user input word like: /(substring1)[a-z]`*`(substring2)/ but it turned out really difficult to dynamically create the expression for every possible user input(given the scope of this exercise being basic string manipulation).
In the case of "gossss" how can i make sure that the 1st "s" is part of the `*` and not the final "s" in the word go`*`s?
Any thoughts on this?

Comment: If you consider it as a state machine, any `s` just takes you to an accepting state, another `s` there stays in the same state, while something else goes back to the "star" state. At the end of input you just check whether the machine is in an accepting state. Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton#Complete_and_incomplete

Comment: @Arkku To get this straight, I should just check the characters leading up to the "star" operator one-to-one being equal and only handling the * as an FSA? Once i finish with it i  could then go on comparing the remaining characters again one -to -one till i run out of characters?

Comment: Conceptually the "check the characters … one-to-one" is a state machine as well, your state being the index of the character you are checking.

Comment: What problems did you encounter building a regex? It should be really straightforward: change `*` to `.*` and backslash-escape any other regex metacharacter. (However, there is a well-known dynamic programming solution to this problem which runs in time proportional to the product of the length of the input and the length of the pattern. Perhaps your instructor was hoping you would find that algorithm.)